# Python Modules in Docker: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, docker

I know this is a common problem, but after having search the web for about an hour, no solution has worked yet. The code works locally but in Docker I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

It's driving me insane b/c no matter how I structure the code, I get either this one or a path not found error, but either way, something I do is just off the charts/

In a nutshell, I am building a dockerized monitor for a shaky gateway that tests every couple of minutes if the gateway host is still reachable and the gateway itself still working. That gateway.

The folder structure is simple:

```
 monitor
    - src 
       - api
       - __init__
       EmailManager.py
       GatewayManager.py
   CONTACT.py # contains email addresses
   main.py
```

The module **init** looks like so:

```
from src.api.EmailManager import EmailManager
from src.api.GatewayManager import GatewayManager
```

Each of those two classes follows a fairly standard pattern. taking the EmailManager as an example:

```
class EmailManager(object):
    def __init__(self, default_address):
    
    def send_email()...
```

Nothing special here, as far as I'm concerned. The main.py contains both, a MainClass and a simple main function to run.

```
from src.api.EmailManager import EmailManager
from src.api.GatewayManager import GatewayManager
from src.CONTACT import ADMIN_EMAIL

class MainClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.em = EmailManager(default_address=ADMIN_EMAIL)
        .... 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mc = MainClass()

    def signal_handler(sig, frame):
        print('Handle signal {signal}'.format(signal=sig))
        mc.shutdown()

    print("Register SIGTERM event handler")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

    print("Start gateway monitor")
    mc.run(minutes=1)
```

This works well on my workstation and roughly does what it is supposed to do. The matching Dockerfile is also very simple:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

COPY config/requirements.txt .
COPY src /src

CMD 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./src/main.py" ]
```

That one throws the ModuleNotFound error.

When changing the last line to

> CMD [ "python", "-m", "./src/main.py" ]

I get the following error:

> /usr/local/bin/python: Relative module names not supported

Any idea how to structure the classes so that they run well in Docker?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Confused on your folder structure. Does the `api` folder contain anything?

Comment: Btw it's always a good practice to set the `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile - not doing that can be one of the reasons for not being able to find modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tree structure is a little confusing, but going off the imports, your folder structure should be looking like so:

```
├── main.py
└── src
    ├── CONTACT.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── api
        ├── EmailManager.py
        ├── GatewayManager.py
        └── __init__.py
```

From there, your `main.py` would look like so (as you have it):

```py
from src.api.EmailManager import EmailManager
from src.api.GatewayManager import GatewayManager
from src.CONTACT import ADMIN_EMAIL
```

Comment: Thanks that sheds some light on the case. However, when I do that, I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.src'; '__main__' is not a package

Do I need to stuff the main.py also in a __init__.py file?

Comment: I'm still confused on your folder structure. Is it looking the same as the tree structure I posted above, or is `main.py` inside your `src` folder?

Comment: I move the main outside src, as you suggested. Otherwise, it is the exact same as your tree.

Comment: In your `Dockerfile`, do you now have `CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]`?

Comment: I have:

> CMD [ "python", "-m", "main.py" ]

And the error I get is:

>  Error while finding module specification for 'main.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
 'main')

Comment: There are a couple of things. First thing is that you are not copying `main.py` into the container, and the second thing is that you are not coping the `src` folder into the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) that `FROM python:3.8-slim-buster` likely places you in. Make sure to do the following: `COPY src ./src` and `COPY main.py .`.

Comment: Yes, COPY src ./src
with the dot did the trick. Thank you so much. Case solved.

Comment: Awesome man, my pleasure. Good luck on the rest of the project!

Comment: Just to add: the `__init__.py` file allows you to "link" Python objects directly to the module. If your `__init__.py` inside of `api` includes (say) `from EmailManager import EmailManager` then inside `main.py` you may chose to do `from src.api import EmailManager` to import the _object_ `EmailManager`, without having to do `from src.api.EmailManager import EmailManager`. That's the use for `__init__.py`.

Comment: If you ever used `requests`, you know that you don't do `import requests` and then `requests.api.get("...")`, and instead, you do `requests.get("...")`. This is because [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py#L123) they defined their `get` import inside the projects main `__init__.py` file, which allows the user to then directly access `get` via the `requests` module, as opposed to having to go down folder structures.

Comment: I don't use requests. Instead,I use sockets to test if a host can be reached over network an then the broker API wrapper ib_insync to get some generic data. The thing is, the IB gateway is kinda infamous in the sense that it needs daily restarts to run okay, but if your app ever crashes and fails to close a connection, in most cases you have to restart the gateway, which isn't exactly helpful. Therefore, I work a lot around these issue to enforce graceful shutdown with a proper disconnect.
Thing is, python modules & code structure is just very different from how you do it Java...

Comment: Now I get it, the module init kinda shortens the path. That is kinda useful and similar to the companion object in Scala.

Comment: The `requests` example above was just to clarify what `__init__.py` is for. However, now that you mentioned the setup for the gateway being an issue, this problem was resolved in the `HTTP/1.1` protocol with a simple [`Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive#Examples). I assume you aren't using `HTTP/1.1` being you are using sockets, but perhaps a useful add-on to whatever protocol (I assume something custom) you guys are using to mitigate the need for a restart.

Comment: ... or, gateway should just close connection after a few moments of no response. [`Connection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header also helps in this cause in `HTTP/1.1`. Perhaps something to consider. Best of luck!

Comment: Gateway is a closed source binary... So yea, it isn't exactly fun to work with. That being said, if the client is well-behaving, it can run stable. I take a look into the keep alive http request, maybe that's opens a different path. However, the current solution with socket & data pull every 5 min actually works as long as the client runs stable. Anyway, thanks for the super fast help!

Comment: Closed binaries are the devil - not fun at all. My pleasure and good luck.